# Add NFS mount to auto.direct when already mounted

Tags: linux, nfs, rhel6

I have a production server which has an NFS Share mounted via fstab. We now need to switch this to autofs to reduce some startup dependencies.

Is it possible to delete the fstab entry and add an autofs entry without unmounting the file system?

I'm guessing that autofs will try to mount at the same mount point as soon as i access the file system, but i'm not completely sure.

As there is an application server which is accessing the file system, its not possible to have the share unmounted prior to adding the autofs entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do then is remove it from fstab, put in autofs, set autofs to start at reboot, but don't enable it yet.  That way when system is rebooted it will come up.  However, if you happen to restart the application before reboot, you can umount the fs and start autofs before starting the app.

Comment: Wow, how could i not think about that solution. Simple and easy. Thanks.